# How is type safety possible for an object pointer of id?

Tags: objective-c, types, type-safety, message-passing

I have the following class (picked out of a Apple example):

```
@interface LeTemperatureAlarmService : NSObject <CBPeripheralDelegate>
@property (readonly) CBPeripheral *servicePeripheral;
@end
```

and in a different class's method I use the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *connectedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
... // Adding some myService objects to connectedServices

for (id service in connectedServices) {
    if ([service servicePeripheral] == parameter) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the thing which drives me crazy is the part where I can send `servicePeripheral` to `service`.

As far as I understand how `id` works, it's basically a pointer which can be literally point to any object. My `NSMutableArray` is an untyped array which can hold any type of object in it, even mixed, so I don't have to be careful what I put in.

So how can it be that I can use `[service servicePeripheral]` even though I never specified the type of service? And how does Xcode know that and even suggest that method in code completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C works different in the respect of method invocation than say C++. The compiler doesn't have to know, because it's not done at compile time, methods are invoked at runtime. Specifically, methods are send to objects, instead of called on them. You send the `servicePeripheral` method to the object and the runtime takes care of calling the right function. This also makes it possible for you to send methods to `nil` without crashing (it will return `false/0/NULL`)

Types in Objective-C are mostly used for compile time safety, which you lose with your approach. The compiler can't warn you that the types don't match, for instance, your array can very well contain `NSString` instances or anything, and the compiler can't help you there since you tell it that you expect `id` (aka anything, really) and `servicePeripheral` is a perfectly valid and known method. You can add type safety by checking the class of the object at runtime using `isKindOfClass:`, for example like this:

```
for (id service in connectedServices) {
    if ([service isKindOfClass:[LeTemperatureAlarmService class]] && [service servicePeripheral] == parameter) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But how is it possible for XCode to suggest servicePeripheral in Code Completion? Is that just a wild guess than?

Comment: @Evils Yes. Note that the code completion will allow you to send any method to an object with type `id`. By the way, it's `Xcode` not `XCode`

Comment: Sending a method to nil will never return NULL. It will return nil.

Comment: @CrimsonChris nil, NULL, false and 0 are all the same.

Comment: Not to be confused with NSNull, which is different. Sorry, I hear null and I think NSNull.

Answer (score 2):

> So how can it be that I can use `[service servicePeripheral]` even though I never specified the type of service?

It is exactly *because* you declared `service` as an `id`. This tells the compiler to turn off all static type-checking and permit you to send *any* message to `service`. That is what `id` *is*: it is the universal recipient (any message can be sent to it, any object value can be assigned to it) and the universal donor (it can be assigned to any object variable).

And you are perfectly right to be wary of this, since it can cause you to crash later. It is *not* (as your question title has it) "type safety". It is type unsafety! The compiler will happily let you say (for example) `[service count]` (because `service` is typed as an `id`), but you will crash later when the app runs, because this object does not respond to the `count` message.

So don't do that! Use explicit types so the compiler can help you in advance.

Comment: And see my full discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_typecasting_and_the_id_type

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I read your discussion on this topic, sadly google didn't pointed me in this direction with my initial search.